# What happened to StandardStyles.xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

What has happened to the StandardStyles.xaml file for Windows Store app projects? I'm trying to add a PRINT button to the AppBar but it's not in intellisense or Properties pane but I know it's in StandardStyles file because I've used it in the past (about a year ago). Why isn't the standard styles file anywhere to be found and how do I get it back and use it properly as I could use it in the past?

All I've found online are a bunch of blog posts mentioning that it's been removed and replaced by generic.xaml but no mention of how to get it in my project.

Comment: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/10/29/remove-standardstyles-xaml-from-windows-8-1-winrt-projects.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant thanks but generic.xaml does not include all of the stuff StandardStyles does. Doesn't matter anymore. I'll just make my own bloody icons.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there has never been a `PrintAppBarButtonStyle` in `StandardStyles.xaml`, because Microsoft wants you to do printing only using the Charms bar under *Devices*.

In general, the syntax `<Button Style="{StaticResource XXXAppBarButtonStyle}" />` has been replaced by the new [`AppBarButton` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) that is used as follows:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="XXX" Label="Descriptive text" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
```

For a list of all alvailable icons, refer to the [Symbol enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) - however, also this one lacks a print symbol unfortunately.

Comment: incorrect. I have used it many times. I even have an app already published over a year ago in the Windows Store using that print button. And yes, I am already using AppBarButton. So my question still stands, how do we regain access to the StandardStyles file? Where is it? And why was it removed?

Answer (score 0):

StandardStyles.xaml was replaced with generic.xaml. Read more [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d49a7608-daef-4d68-8b4b-b54dbc0ec1a7/cant-find-gt-commonstandardstylesxaml-in-my-project?forum=winappswithcsharp):